# Passing different number of the arguments

Tags: haskell

I have this:

```
(Aeson.Object jsonObject) -> case (HashMap.lookup "high" jsonObject, HashMap.lookup "low" jsonObject) of
 (Just (String val), Just (String val2)) -> [val, val2]
 _ -> error "Couldn't get both keys"
```

I'd like to be able to pass "high" and "low" as the arguments and do the pattern matching over them to retrieve their actual values from Json. And, of course, the number of such the arguments can vary.

```
parseJson :: [String] -> [String]
parseJson keys =
  (Aeson.Object jsonObject) -> case (?????) of
     (?????) -> ????
     _ -> error "Couldn't retrieve the keys"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. I assume that `(AesonObject.jsonObject)` refers to a case of an existing case expression, as it's not syntactically valid otherwise.

```
import Control.Monad ( sequence )

getString (Just (String value)) = Just value
getString _ = Nothing

parseJson :: [String] -> [String]
parseJson keys =
  case ... of
      (Aeson.Object jsonObject) ->
         case sequence (map (getString . flip HashMap.lookup jsonObject) keys) of
             Just values -> values
             _ -> error "Couldn't retrieve the keys"
```

`flip HashMap.lookup jsonObject` gives you a lookup function from a key to a value (which is a `Maybe`. Composing that with `getString` gives us something that only succeeds on `String` values, in the same way that your existing inline pattern-match does.

Finally, [`sequence`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3asequence) on the `Maybe` monad turns `[Maybe String]` into `Maybe [String]`, only returning a `Just` for the output if all the elements of the input are `Just`.

Comment: `sequence` and `map` combined is `mapM`.

Comment: what's "case ... of"?

Comment: I was assuming you had some outer `case` expression - if so, then the `...` just refers to whatever you were inspecting in that expression.

Comment: Could you explain what the order of operations in `(getString . flip HashMap.lookup jsonObject)` is? From the right to the left?

Comment: Yes. First do the lookup, then call getString.